# How to enable experimental Docker CLI features

Tags: docker, configuration, command-line-interface

I'm trying to use `docker manifest inspect <image name>`, but the Docker CLI says...

```sh
$ docker manifest inspect node
docker manifest inspect is only supported on a Docker cli with experimental cli features enabled
```

Considering the wealth of Docker documentation, this simple question is surprisingly difficult to search for.

How do I enable experimental CLI features?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem:

1. Specify the environment variable

   `export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled`

   This provides a temporary environment for testing the experimental features without having to commit to it's usage.
2. Docker config file

   Add `"experimental": "enabled"` to `~/.docker/config.json` *(default location)* at the beginning of the file and not at the end *(important detail)*

   > ***NOTE:** The Docker config file only appears after you have run `docker login` for the first time.*
   >   This is the best option, if you wish to permanently enable experimental mode.

Comment: Could you explain why at the beginning and not at the end given that it is important?

Comment: I looked at the `.config` file, it's only JSON and there is no obvious reason why it should be first instead of last. I assume I discovered this a note during my research. If you look at the Docker documentation, you will see it on the first line of their example, however I didn't see the comment that explains it must be there.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use an experimental feature once without exporting a variable. Like typing command with docker command:
`DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled docker manifest inspect hello-world`
In this case, you will not need to unset variable if needed.