# How do I make multi-arch Docker images?

Tags: linux, docker, x86, raspberry-pi, arm

I've created a Dockerfile for a CLI utility, and it works great on my Linux laptop. I tried running the container on a Raspberry Pi with Docker installed, but it won't work.

I know myriad companies create images to support multiple architectures, how are they doing this?

I want to know, because I want the container for the CLI to be deployable to a Raspberry Pi, as well as my Linux laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59365141/596285

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know other companies create images to support multiple architectures, how are they doing this?

The quick answer is that it is *NOT* possible to create a single image that will support multiple architectures. However, it appears as if one image will satisfy multiple architectures because you are actually interacting with [a manifest file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest/). A manifest file acts as a pointer to the correct image based on the Docker client that requested the image.

For example, you can run `docker build` on an `x86_64` platform *(e.g. your Linux laptop)* and again on an `armv7l` platform *(e.g. a Raspberry Pi)*, and two completely different images will be created. The resulting images should be given platform specific names and pushed to your Docker image repository (e.g. `hub.docker.com`).

Once that has been completed, then you will need to [enable experimental mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937733/how-to-enable-experimental-docker-cli-features) in the Docker CLI, and [create and upload a manifest file](https://developer.ibm.com/linuxonpower/2017/07/27/create-multi-architecture-docker-image/) with a platform neutral name that points to the corresponding platform specific images.

**TL;DR** These three commands will do the trick *(assuming you are working from the `x86_64` machine)*

```
docker manifest create <new-list-ref-name> <image-ref> [<image-ref>...]
docker manifest annotate <new-list-ref-name> <image-ref> --os linux --arch arm
docker manifest push <new-list-ref-name> [--purge]
```

***NOTE:** Depending on whether or not you are using a multi-arch base image, you may not need the `docker manifest annotate` step.*

***NOTE:** When pushing a manifest file (i.e. `docker manifest push ...`), be sure to use the `--purge` option; it is not discussed in the linked articles. Not using `--purge`, will cause you heartache if you plan on using a tag that will be reused at a later time (e.g. `latest`).*

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your `--purge` note? What happens if it isn't included?

Comment: Without `--purge`, the manifest file you create will linger on your local host. This may be desirable when you are referencing a specific and immutable tag, but this creates conflicts when making a common tag (e.g. `latest`) which may be created over and over again. Without `--purge` you will have difficulty correctly updating your manifest to reflect the current hashes of the newest images, and it's hard to tell why.
I view this as similar to using `docker run` with `--rm`.

Comment: In which cases do I need to specify `--arch` and `--os`?

Comment: I am not sure. In fact, I was surprised when I discovered it was unnecessary for multi-arch `FROM` images. I just thought I would share the note. It definitely works with them explicitly stated, so I would probably just provide the parameters if possible.

Also, if you research and discover a more accurate answer, please share here! :)

Comment: You're a lifesaver with the purge option. Saved me some headache

Answer (score 4):

[buildx](https://github.com/docker/buildx) can be used to generate a multi-arch manifest list and images that are pushed to a registry. When you pull that from the registry, the appropriate manifest for your platform is retrieved.

This is available in 19.03 as a CLI plugin that is available when the CLI is in experimental mode. You can enable this by:

```
export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
```

For a multi-node builder environment, configure your builder instance with `docker buildx create`, using the `--append` option to add more nodes to the builder. Then `docker buildx use` on that builder to use the instance for your commands.

For building on a single node with emulation, that can be done on debian based systems by installing the latest `qemu-user-static` (package name may vary for other Linux distributions), e.g.:

```
apt-get install -t testing qemu-user-static
```

For an explanation of why a newer release is needed, see:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868030
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+bug/1815100

Once you have qemu installed with binfmt_misc setup with the `F` flag in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-*`, then you can cross compile on your local host using:

```
docker buildx create --driver docker-container --name local \
  --use unix:///var/run/docker.sock
docker buildx inspect --bootstrap local
```

You then build the multi-architecture image with:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 \
  -t $registry_img_and_tag --output type=registry .
```

Include each platform you want to support with `--platform`.

I've got a [presentation covering this](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/docker-build/presentation.html#cross-platform). Use `P` to see the presenter notes. Using `FROM --platform=$TARGETPLATFROM` is useful to avoid needing to pull fresh images for other platforms.