# Why does docker use outdated :latest when working with multi-arch images?

Tags: git, docker

Running Docker on OSX, doing multi-arch build. My problem is, that using the `:latest` tag, an outdated image is built or pulled. Here's what happens.

Cleanup:

```
docker image rm -f volkszaehler/mbmd:latest volkszaehler/mbmd:0.10
```

Multi-arch build:

```
docker build -t volkszaehler/mbmd:0.10-amd64 -t volkszaehler/mbmd:latest-amd64 -f linux-amd64-.Dockerfile .
docker push volkszaehler/mbmd:0.10-amd64
docker push volkszaehler/mbmd:latest-amd64
docker manifest create --amend volkszaehler/mbmd:0.10 volkszaehler/mbmd:0.10-amd64
docker manifest annotate volkszaehler/mbmd:0.10 volkszaehler/mbmd:0.10-amd64 --os=linux --arch=amd64
docker manifest push volkszaehler/mbmd:0.10
docker manifest create --amend volkszaehler/mbmd:latest volkszaehler/mbmd:latest-amd64
docker manifest annotate volkszaehler/mbmd:latest volkszaehler/mbmd:latest-amd64 --os=linux --arch=amd64
docker manifest push volkszaehler/mbmd:latest
```

Test the amd64 version directly (`e83718d` is the current git commit - OK):

```
docker run volkszaehler/mbmd:latest-amd64 run -a 192.168.0.1:502 -d mpm:5
2020/04/28 05:54:57 mbmd 0.10 (e83718d)
```

Test the manifest version:

```
docker run volkszaehler/mbmd:latest run -a 192.168.0.1:502 -d mpm:5     
Unable to find image 'volkszaehler/mbmd:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from volkszaehler/mbmd
e6b0cf9c0882: Already exists 
091e8a40b217: Already exists 
01dff8bc2c5b: Already exists 
5fa7edce914c: Already exists 
20370734a95f: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:e52d6212bac3026ee619c4b6a646035fb93827ed3cd1f5f536acb74b53646eca
Status: Downloaded newer image for volkszaehler/mbmd:latest
2020/04/28 05:55:05 mbmd 851ad89 (851ad89)
```

Now `851ad89` is an outdated commit. Its also obvious that `volkszaehler/mbmd:latest` is not available locally and must be pulled.

Why is docker not choosing the local amd64 image that is part of the manifest and instead needs to pull an outdated latest? Why does the remote latest on the registry remain outdated?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375

Comment: Seems the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59613303/how-do-i-make-multi-arch-docker-images/59613304#59613304, using --purge when publishing the manifest. Still need to double-check.